# EPR Paradox and Density Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, epr-experiment

I am curious how one can use a density matrix in the following familiar cases in QM.

**1. EPR**

Suppose a typical EPR situation where the state of a two-electron system is given by

$\alpha|1\rangle|2\rangle+\beta|2\rangle|1\rangle$.

How do you get the state of the $individual$ electron using a density matrix?

**2. Another Situation**

Suppose a different situation that there is an electron of which state is prepared to be $\alpha|1\rangle +\beta|2\rangle$ at a time $t_{1}$, where $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ are orthonormal states of the electron and $\alpha^{2} + \beta^{2}=1$.

Alice observes the electron at $t_{2}$ w.r.t. $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$, and finds out that the electron is in $|1\rangle$.

So, Alice describes the electron system as follows:

$t_{1} \rightarrow t_{2} : \alpha|1\rangle + \beta|2\rangle \rightarrow |1\rangle$.

In fact, Alice and the electron (and whatever measurements devise Alice has) are all in a closed box, outside of which is another observer, Bob. Bob knows the initial condition of Alice at $t_{1}$ so he describes the evolution of the electron-Alice system as follows:

$t_{1} \rightarrow t_{2} : (\alpha|1\rangle + \beta|2\rangle) \otimes|Alice, initial\rangle \rightarrow \alpha|1\rangle \otimes|Alice1 \rangle + \beta|2\rangle \otimes|Alice2\rangle$,

where $|Alice1(2)\rangle$ denotes the state of Alice obtaining the measurement value 1(2). Then what is the state of the electron $alone$ from the perspective of Bob? Is it $\alpha|1\rangle\langle1| + \beta|2\rangle\langle2|$?

Comment: For the second, might be worth looking up "Wigner's friend".

Comment: For the first question, the state of one electron is described by the reduced density matrix. Namely, start from the density matrix of two electrons and trace out the other electron.